# Removing Ubuntu 14.04 and re-install 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, system-installation, dvd, downgrade

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS from 12.04 LTS and realised that it is simply not right for this particular computer (I do still plan to use 14.04 with my newer machines).  I wish to completely remove ver. 14.04 and replace it with 12.04... no roll-back or anything necessary. Happy just to restore/fresh reinstall 12.04 just as it was. 
I am even using the exact same DVD that I used to install 12.04 originally when I sucessfully switched from Windows. When I try to boot from the DVD, it just seems to go no further than the screen that shows the word Ubuntu and the series of red dots below it (lighting in succession) to indicate "progress". Only thing is.. the led light on the CD/DVD-Rom drive stops flickering after a minute or two, as though it is no longer being read. For a long time.
The computer does not freeze, but is otherwise unresponsive. Could it be that it will just take a very long time to begin the process of (re)installing 12.04 (like "overnight" long) and we should be more patient - or am I simply going about this the wrong way? 
Any advice, including the correct/conventional way to "downgrade" a version of Ubuntu would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I would open the tray and reboot, preferably with alt-ctrl-del if possible. It should not take that long to load. But, if you have unlimit data, or even the .iso on a PC, you might want to try a fresh dvd, if that one shows signs of wear. I would completely understand if your on a machine with Rambus or something, but if you had it on your system, your system should be capable of loading the cd in a timely fashion.

getting a .iso of Precise can be done from:

http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/

and it's the latest, so less time doing updates after install.

Answer (score 0):

I just did this the other day on my Girlfriend's laptop. I had to uninstall 14.04 LTS because her usb wireless adpater ALFA AWUS036 was extremely slow (I suspected a driver problem). I put in a whole day trying to get it to work, but no dice. I'm thinking something is up with the Linux 3.13 Kernel. Anyways, I manged to so snag an .iso from http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/ and from there I plugged in a 2GB USB Flash Drive and used Startup Disk Creator to make a Bootable USB Drive. From there it was just a matter of booting the usb key and re installing Ubuntu 12.04 LTS again.

Answer (score 0):

You can reinstall ubuntu 12.04 by **rebooting** and press **F3** to go to the boot option. 
**Enter 'C'** to go to the command prompt and type "**coreboot_boottime**". You will see the familiar 12.04 menu to install ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Wait, what? This makes no sense...